# Handling null reference

Tags: java, null, nullreferenceexception

```
Public Static Void Main() {
    LinkedList q = new LinkedList();
    q.enqueue(Object);
    System.out.println(q.deque().getString()); //it will print the string of the popped object
}
```

If the queue becomes empty, it will give exception as q.deque() refers to null and any method on null will give exception.

we can achieve this by changing it to:

```
Object k = q.dequeue();
if(k != null)
System.out.println(k.getString());
```

Is there any better way to do this instead of checking null pointer in the main program?

Comment: If you were using `Object.toString` instead of whatever `getString` method you've defined, `System.out.println(q.deque())` would print out the string `"null"` if the element was null.  Other than that, you've basically got the best solution you can get.

Comment: You can probably check for `isEmpty()` or something on the `q` prior to calling `deque()`. But you have to check for something somewhere.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Do you mean `Objects.toString`? Small difference but it can be confusing

Comment: No, I don't; I mean `Object.toString`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean, calling `Object.toString` will throw `NullPointerException` with null input. `Objects` is the class for null-safe operations

Comment: I mean that if you _override_ `Object.toString()` in the element class, then `System.out.println(q.deque())` will call `String.valueOf(q.deque())`, which returns the string `"null"` when passed a null object.  The OP defined some weird method named `getString()`, however, which would not get the benefits of this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per java best coding practice, if you have a method returning a collection such as list/set/map and in case when the collection has no elements in it, then it is always good to retunr empty collection instead of null.

For example you can use for list:

```
return Collections.emptyList(); // when the list is empty instead of return null
```

This saves null pointer exception on the calling code if programmer has missed null pointer check.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of `LinkedList` you are using since the version that ships with JDK is generic and doesn't have `dequeue()` and `queue(..)` methods but the most reasonable way to do it would be to have a `isEmpty()` method so that you can do:

```
while (!q.isEmpty()) {
  S.O.P(q.deque().getString());
}
```

Notice that this functionality is present for all the collections that ships with JDK, as it is declared in `Collection<E>` interface.

Answer (score 0):

As per good coding practices, always return an empty collection.

```
List: Collections.emptyList()
Set: Collections.emptySet()
Map: Collections.emptyMap()
```

Above helps:

- avoid NPE - NullPointerException
- extra check needed if the collection is null or not before iterating it over
- immutable collections object, if the caller tried to modify the collection, gets UnsupportedOperationException